# How to I expand JSON data in kusto/data explorer that has nested data?

Tags: kql, adx

I am trying to ingest JSON array data into Azure data explorer, as per this Microsoft article. (Only the JSON Array section) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-json-formats?tabs=kusto-query-language

I have one table with two columns(messageId,Message) message contain json data and i want to extract this data into different columns. all of the fields from the array are just blank.

enter code here
{ 'data': { 'type': 'ABC', 'id': '1234567890', 'attributes': { 'event': 'update', 'logged_at': '2021-06-03T15:41:22.000Z', 'heartbeat_id': '12345678', 'gps_valid': True, 'gps': { 'distance_diff': 0.22, 'total_distance': 127.79 }, 'hdop': 12, 'fuel_level': 180.4, 'relative_position': { 'distance': '3', 'country_code': 'Uk' } },`

CODE: AMO | mv-expand data = message.data | extend type = data.type, id = data.id` }

Comment: *all of the fields from the array are just blank*: could you please clarify which array you're referring to? the JSON payload you've included includes no properties that are arrays. it'd also be helpful if, for the given input, you'll include the expected output that matches it

Comment: I want every filed as column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there's no property-bag/array you need to expand (using `mv-expand`), rather you can extend/project the properties of your choice directly, e.g:

```
print message = dynamic({
    "data": {
        "type": "ABC",
        "id": "1234567890",
        "attributes": {
            "event": "update",
            "logged_at": "2021-06-03T15:41:22.000Z",
            "heartbeat_id": "12345678",
            "gps_valid": true,
            "gps": {
                "distance_diff": 0.22,
                "total_distance": 127.79
            },
            "hdop": 12,
            "fuel_level": 180.4,
            "relative_position": {
                "distance": "3",
                "country_code": "Uk"
            }
        }
    }
})
| project message.data.id, message.data.type
```

| message_data_id | message_data_type |
| --- | --- |
| 1234567890 | ABC |

Comment: I tryied that one also .| mv-expand message
|extend  type=message.data.type ..but still i am geeting blank output.when i use static json data at that time it will work fine ..but when i used json data column from table then it don't gave the output

Comment: it could be due to the fact that your payload isn't actually valid JSON - instead of double quotes (`"`) it used single quotes (`'`) - and therefore can't be properly parsed, and you can't access its properties.

Comment: Yes actually my json data is not double quoted it is encapsulate in single quotes.